# docker postgres, fail to map volume in windows

Tags: postgresql, docker

I wish to store my persists data in my local D:\dockerData\postgres9.6. Below is my docker command

```
docker pull postgres
docker run -d -v /d/dockerData/postgres9.6:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

It successful create a container and I can use pgAdmin to access and create database.

But I found out that there is no file in my D:\dockerData\postgres9.6. I exec bash into the container, there is at least 20+ files inside /var/lib/postgresql/data.

Anyone can point out which part goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what kind of Docker you are using on Windows:

- [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) with VirtualBox: only C:\Users\mylogin is shared by default. D:\ is not mounted.
- [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) with HyperV: only C:\ is mounted by default. Make sure D:\ is a shared drive: [see image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4042769/18486466/1c03ee4e-79bf-11e6-96cc-5d96d236b967.gif)